# Why doesn't my browser cache this this page?

Tags: html, apache, http, caching, browser-cache

Why doesn't my browser cache this this page?  I've used multiple browsers.  When looking at my Apache access log, I get something similar to the following, and am also curious why the first hit is different that following hits.  The follow hits are the same regardless of whether I click the link to reload, or manually refresh the page.

```
12.123.12.123- - [26/Oct/2013:07:17:43 -0700] "GET /testing/caching1/cacheMe.html HTTP/1.1" 200 286 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)"
12.123.12.123 - - [26/Oct/2013:07:18:03 -0700] "GET /testing/caching1/cacheMe.html HTTP/1.1" 200 286 "http://badobe.com/testing/caching1/cacheMe.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0"
12.123.12.123 - - [26/Oct/2013:07:21:25 -0700] "GET /testing/caching1/cacheMe.html HTTP/1.1" 200 286 "http://badobe.com/testing/caching1/cacheMe.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0"



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">
        <title>Cache Me!</title>
    </head>
    <body><a href='cacheMe.html'>Click Me</a></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your second question:

Most likely what happened was:

1. You typed the url in the browser (no referrer line in the log)
2. You clicked on the link to the page (referrer line in the log)
3. You then refreshed the page, the browser sent *exactly* the same headers with the same referrer

Alternatively your browser was sending "last visited page from domain" as the referrer. As not not upset some sites that don't like deep linking.